# DeprecationWarning in ROS 2 Foxy

Tags: ros2, nvidia, jetson, ros-foxy

I am working on a project where a remote in a Jetson Nano on an RC-Car from my Laptop to run ROS2 Nodes.
So far everything is working fine despite of this warning, but i'm wondering if it can lead to problems later on.

Below is the demo talker node:

```
anassq@anassq-ThinkPad:-$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [1693382772.600519335] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1693382773.600493124] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[INFO] [1693382774.600495367] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
^C[INFO] [1693382775.563863256] [rcicpp]: signal_handler(signal_value=2)
anassq@anassq-ThinkPad:-$
```

Below is the demo listener node:

```
jetson@nano:—$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
/opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
 from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
[INFO] [1693382772.604064646] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[INFO] [1693382773.596332466] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
[INFO] [1693382774.595766385] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 3]
^C[INFO] [1693382891.440914460] [rcicpp]: signal_handler(signal_value=2)
jetson@nano:—$
```

**Please Note:** The Ubuntu image i flashed on the jetson-nano comes with already installer python and many other packages. Here is the source of that image: https://github.com/Qengineering/Jetson-Nano-Ubuntu-20-image

I tried updating the system and the rosdep, but it didn't work.
Does anyone have a suggestion to how this could be solved ?

Thanks a lot for the read

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I could grab text from your screenshots and modify the question already. However, in the future, please note that it is better to paste the text from the error rather than a screenshot. Images are not text-searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

It is a warning coming from the colcon-core module of ROS 2. Please ignore it as it does not affect any functionality of ROS. Feel free to read more at https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/552

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks a lot ! for the read and for your answer.
I managed on the last hour to solve it. By downgrading setuptools.

Comment: `jetson@nano:~$ pip3 list | grep setuptools
setuptools                           68.1.2`
And then:                                                                              
`jetson@nano:~$ pip3 install setuptools==58.2.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting setuptools==58.2.0
  Downloading setuptools-58.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 946.1/946.1 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: setuptools`

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
And then it was gone !